# reduce without return but assign to a variable failed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using reduce is it possible to sum all the value without returning it but assign it to a outer variable? I got error of NAN using below code.

```
const raw = [{
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 13,
    "female_count": 13
  }, {
    "male_count": 452,
    "female_count": 470
  }]
}, {
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 1,
    "female_count": 2
  }, {
    "male_count": 58,
    "female_count": 32
  }]
}]

let total_male_count, total_female_count = 0
raw.forEach(obj => {
  obj.age_data.reduce((accum, obj2) => {
    total_male_count = accum + obj2.male_count
    total_female_count = accum + obj2.female_count
  }, 0)
})

console.log(total_male_count)
console.log(total_female_count)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L6ttsL8t/

I'm not sure what's wrong with the `accum`, `obj2.male_count` did return value.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but *why would you want to do that*!? The whole point of `reduce` is not to use side effects on outer-scope variables. You should some `for … of` loops if you wanted to use this approach.

Comment: You can reduce each subpart, calculate sum and then update the global variables. check my answer for a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `reduce` if you're not using its return value. For what you're doing, just use `forEach`.

Your `total_male_count` is not initialized, so it starts out containing `undefined` (you've only initialized `total_female_count`). Further, you just want to add to the `total_...` variables, not use an accumulator.

So, initialize it, add to the existing variables, and use the correct "looping" function, and you'll get the correct value.

```
let total_male_count = 0, total_female_count = 0
// -----------------^^^^
raw.forEach(obj => {
  obj.age_data.forEach(obj2 => {
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
    total_male_count += obj2.male_count
// ------------------^^
    total_female_count += obj2.female_count
// --------------------^^
  }, 0)
})
```

Live Example:

```js
const raw = [{
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 13,
    "female_count": 13
  }, {
    "male_count": 452,
    "female_count": 470
  }]
}, {
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 1,
    "female_count": 2
  }, {
    "male_count": 58,
    "female_count": 32
  }]
}]

let total_male_count = 0, total_female_count = 0
raw.forEach(obj => {
  obj.age_data.forEach(obj2 => {
    total_male_count += obj2.male_count
    total_female_count += obj2.female_count
  }, 0)
})

console.log(total_male_count)
console.log(total_female_count)
```

Comment: this is correct, I'm not sure why reduce came into my mind at the first place.

Comment: @CeciliaChan: Well, `reduce` would be a good fit for doing a *single* sum, so that's probably why.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var total_male_count= 0;

var total_female_count = 0;



for(var i of raw){

for(var j of i.age_data){

total_male_count += j.male_count;
total_female_count += j.female_count;

}


}

console.log(total_male_count);
console.log(total_female_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using two `array#reduce`, inner reduce sums the male and female count of each `age_data` while the outer reduce sums the `age_data`

```js
const raw = [{"age_data": [{"male_count": 13,"female_count": 13}, {"male_count": 452,"female_count": 470}]
}, {"age_data": [{"male_count": 1,"female_count": 2}, {"male_count": 58,"female_count": 32}]}]

var output = raw.reduce ((sum, obj) => {
  let temp = obj.age_data.reduce((accum, obj2) => {
    accum.total_male_count += obj2.male_count;
    accum.total_female_count += obj2.female_count;
    return accum;
  }, {total_male_count : 0, total_female_count: 0});
  sum.total_male_count += temp.total_male_count;
  sum.total_female_count += temp.total_female_count;
  return sum;
},{total_male_count : 0, total_female_count: 0})

console.log(output)
```

You don't need reduce, this could be accomplished through two `forEach`. Plus you need to initialize `total_male_count = 0`

```js
const raw = [{
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 13,
    "female_count": 13
  }, {
    "male_count": 452,
    "female_count": 470
  }]
}, {
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 1,
    "female_count": 2
  }, {
    "male_count": 58,
    "female_count": 32
  }]
}]

let total_male_count = 0, total_female_count = 0
raw.forEach(obj => {
  obj.age_data.forEach((obj2) => {
    total_male_count += obj2.male_count;
    total_female_count += obj2.female_count;
  })
})

console.log(total_male_count)
console.log(total_female_count)
```

Answer (score -1):

I edited your code for it to work, although this is not the right way to do it

```js
const raw = [{
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 13,
    "female_count": 13
  }, {
    "male_count": 452,
    "female_count": 470
  }]
}, {
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 1,
    "female_count": 2
  }, {
    "male_count": 58,
    "female_count": 32
  }]
}]

let total_male_count= 0, total_female_count = 0
raw.forEach(obj => {
  obj.age_data.reduce((accum, obj2) => {
    total_male_count += obj2.male_count;
    total_female_count += obj2.female_count;
  }, 0)
})

console.log(total_male_count)
console.log(total_female_count)
```

The correct way would be

```js
const raw = [{
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 13,
    "female_count": 13
  }, {
    "male_count": 452,
    "female_count": 470
  }]
}, {
  "age_data": [{
    "male_count": 1,
    "female_count": 2
  }, {
    "male_count": 58,
    "female_count": 32
  }]
}]

let total_male_count= 0, total_female_count = 0
raw.forEach(function(element){
 let obj = element.age_data.reduce((accum, obj2) => {
     return {"male_count": accum.male_count + obj2.male_count,
       "female_count": accum.female_count + obj2.female_count};
   }, {"male_count": 0,
     "female_count": 0});
    total_male_count += obj.male_count;
    total_female_count += obj.female_count;
})


console.log(total_male_count)
console.log(total_female_count)
```